# Change type of id on column which is also a primary key with a ef migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I have the following model:

```
[Key]
public int CustomerSearchConfigId { get; set; }
[Key]
public string CategoryId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(CustomerSearchConfigId))]
public CustomerSearchConfig Config { get; set; }
```

CategoryId is a string, but I have now found out it would need to be an INT.
So I changed the type to an int, ran

```
dotnet ef migrations add AddFieldsAndRenameFields
```

Which produced among other this:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
    name: "CategoryId",
    table: "CustomerSearchConfigTagCategory",
    type: "int",
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)");
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
The object 'PK_CustomerSearchConfigTagCategory' is dependent on column 'CategoryId'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN CategoryId failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

When I search around for it, everyone seems to suggest I just delete it all and start over with a completely new migration history and everything..

Which is not an option!

So, does anybody know how I can change the type of CategoryId to an int without having to nuke my tables, migration, data and sanity?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to delete the database and build it up again in case you don't have any impairment records.
So if you need to keep all of your information in the database see this guidе
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1193009/Changing-primary-key-data-type-in-EF-Core